# How apis outside the web works?

Tags: rest, api

I was studying APIs here, and i can't find any article or anything that can answer: "are there APIs outside the web?"

I use a lot of APIs at work, but http/https on a rails application, anythings outside that, i really don't know what it is.

There are a lot of non-http APIs on the market that i know of, like MetalAPI from iphones, vulkanAPI, both for graphical porposes for what i know

The problem begin when, how does that work? What protocol they use? How they are able to communicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the idea of an API from communication between machines or even between processes.

An API is simply a defined way of calling/executing code that lives outside of the code that you are working on.  This could be doing things locally within your app like using the `Gson` or `Jackson` classes in Java to work with JSON formatted data, generating menus in a C++ application using the Qt or GTK+ or Win32 libraries, etc. or perhaps interprocess communication and requests, like accessing kernel data/functions in utilities like `top` or `iptables`, or it could be between machine communications to get a remote machine to Do Things.

Then you have the between machine or between process communication channels.  This may be two machines talking back and forth doing request/reply things via the HTTP(s) protocol(s) or even direct socket communication, or it could be local machine interprocess communications.

When you talk about an API being a RESTful API, or being a SOAP API, that starts combining all of this and more, defining a "pattern" of how an API operates.  For example, a true RESTful API uses HTTP actions (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) and status codes (200 OK, 204 OK received and processed but no reply data being sent, 404 resource not found, 400 malformed request, etc) to convey meaning. Quite often the web based APIs we use are more REST-like than REST-ful.   Similar definitions exist for SOAP based APIs, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Protocol_concepts